# Entity Framework primary key convention. How to allow more columns with 'id' in their name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing a web app on an existing database which unfortunately I cannot change. 
I get this error

> "More than one property map found for property 'Id' when using case-insensitive search. "

After a little search I found that the problem is that there are some conventions in EF and more specifically one that states (according to what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234513/mvc-4-and-ef6-database-first-issue-with-mapping)) that:

> if the field name contains a suffix of ID (case-insensitive), then EF will automatically include it as a primary key

The table has already a primary key (named 'id').
Is there a way to disable the EF conventions or in any other way to allow having besides my 'id' field, a field named "something_id" without getting this error?

Comment: Code first or Model (.edmx)? Which version of EF?

Comment: What is the name of the extra property that EF considers as PK as well?

Comment: edmx EF version 6
The primary key is named 'id' and the other property is called 'role_id'. I have found how to disable all conventions but dont want to be so harsh and want to disable just the primary key convention.

Comment: have you tried explicitly applying `Key` attribute on your `id` property?

Comment: i think it is already applied
<Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="id" /></Key>
          <Property Name="id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="firstname" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="100" />
          <Property Name="lastname" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="100" />
          <Property Name="username" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="100" />
          <Property Name="password" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="100" />
          <Property Name="role_id" Type="int" />

Comment: It's applied by default convention but I mean if you apply it explicitly, it may understand that that `Id` is the only key without complaining about other columns.

Comment: I think I did that by using the haskey method 

 'modelBuilder.Entity<myUser>().HasKey<int>(l => l.Id).ToTable("mytable")'

I think that the id  field is explicitly defined as primary key, but EF doesnt like that there is the string "id" to another field

Answer (score -1):

this is how to disable the id convention of EF:

inside OnModelCreating

```
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IdKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
```